# parseFloat("10").toFixed(2) gives me "10.00" Now, how do i convert the result to number with the decimal values

Tags: javascript

`parseFloat("10.3232").toFixed(2)`  gives me "10.32"

`parseFloat("10").toFixed(2)` gives me "10.00"

How do I convert the result to number with the decimal values ?

I tried below which removes the .00 decimal part and returns only integer part.

```
+parseFloat("10").toFixed(2) // 10
parseFloat("10").toFixed(2)*1 // 10
```

Comment: The answer is: You can't. Numbers do not have significant digits.

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Comment: can you just not use the number but then `toFixed(2)` whenever you need to show it? What difference does it make that it doesn't include the `.00` when it is a number?

Comment: My requirement demands to display .00 and my result type was 'number'. Any way, i have updated my result type to 'any' which accepts any value type. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is the neat point you actually can't do that with a number succeded by zeros only after decimal since 10 & 10.0000... have same value & datatype(Even float is stored as a Number type) i.e

```
10 === 10.000       //true
```

You can actually convert a decimal string with atleast any single non zero digit after decimal using this:

```
const a = "10.004" * 1
console.log(a, typeof a)  // 10.004  'number'
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I convert the result to number with the decimal values ?

```js
// .toFixed returns a string.
// Convert it to number using Number()
const n = Number(parseFloat("10.3232").toFixed(2));
console.log(n); // 10.32

// Here the decimals are not displayed.
const n2 = Number(parseFloat("10").toFixed(2));
console.log(n2); // 10

// If you need to show zero decimals you will need
// to return it as a string.
const n3 = parseFloat("10").toFixed(2);
console.log(typeof(n3), n3); // string 10.00
```